# Response notification on profile page stays after inbox read

Tags: support, profile-page, notifications, responses

This question is about the fact that the response number on my profile page is still there when I checked the new responses via inbox. Two images to explain:

Inbox is cleared:

[image: empty inbox]

Profile page shows response:

[image: response count]

I have found on meta that the responses tab number shows the number of new responses since your last visit to your profile page, and has nothing to do with having viewed them or not. The problem is, **I could swear** that a week or so ago I never had that number there! Is this just me never having noticed, or has something actually changed?

Comment: It's probably tiny because you've used MediaFire to host your images, whatever that is. Why didn't you use the image hosting that we provide here?

Comment: I took the courtesy to post my own screenshot which reflect your issue clearly hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd that's okay :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing has changed. It's always been this way. You have to open the "responses" tab in order to clear that number.

Viewing the comments, or checking your responses in the global inbox is not connected to this number displayed in the profile page.

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that this is new then? Oh well it'll be me :)

Comment: @Mario that number in the user profile page (for any tab not just responses) means "amount of changes since you last checked those changes" where checking the changes means clicking the tab. Like Cody said, it's totally separate system than the global inbox.