# Clear response notification when notification read from inbox

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove responses from Responses tab once they’ve been read in Inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102153/remove-responses-from-responses-tab-once-theyve-been-read-in-inbox)

Related to [Response notification on profile page stays after inbox read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131560/response-notification-on-profile-page-stays-after-inbox-read), can stackoverflow be enhanced to clear the "message flag" from the Profile > responses tab when the user has already viewed the response (such as when following the link from the notification area)?

Comment: If you believe it to be a dupe then you have your answer (I think it is and am voting that way). There's no harm in leaving dupes around as they help guide people to the "correct"...